# How to change/remap int values to str in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a two dimensional array of int in numpy. I am building sort of ASCI art generator based on TrueType fonts. I have this problem that I want to change all values in certain range to a string. When I do change one value to string, then the rest breaks, because int in the whole arrayis needed for such replacement. Please, how do remap multiple ranges in an array? Thanks

```
data = np.array(list(image.getdata()), dtype=object).reshape(30, 30)
n = 255
data[data > n*0.75] = 'a'
data[data > n*0.5] = 0.75
data[data > n*0.25] = 0.5
data[data > 1] = 0.25
```

Comment: Do all the `data>...` tests first, before you start of modify `data`.  Or do the test and modifications on different arrays (one a copy of the other).

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I have solved that based on your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the values before I turn it to Numpy Array like this

thanks to  @hpaulj

```
def number_to_letter(number):
    n = 255
    if number >= 255*0.75:
        return '#'
    elif number >= 255*0.5:
        return 'O'
    elif number >= 255*0.25:
        return '+'
    elif number >= 1:
        return '-'
    elif number >= 0:
        return ' '

image_data = [number_to_letter(number) for number in image_data]
data = np.array(image_data, dtype=str).reshape(30, 30)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is what @Prune means:

```
data[(n*0.5 <= data) & (data < n*0.75)] = 0.75
data[(n*0.25 <= data) & (data < n*0.5)] = 0.5 
data[(data < n*0.25)] = 0.25
data[data > 0.75] = "A"
```

Comment: but then you have a problem when you want to change your mind and decide that 0.25 should be equal 'B' actually, this is nice example on changing ranges but it's a bit walk around.

Comment: You can then use == which work on both string and float

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1. Do the string replacement *last*, not first
2. Change only the range you want: give both upper and lower limits.  With the sequence you posted, you'll have no `0.75` values.

Comment: well, sorry for not explaining properly but I will have to go through all the values and change it at one point. All 0.75 + values are replace by 'a', they no longer exist so I can look for values 0.5 higher, which doesn't include values higher than 0.75, they are 'a's now